# Is there a way of finding trigonometric ratios of any random angle between 0° to 90° without using a calculator?

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion, approximation

I wanted to know, how to find out trigonometric ratios($\sin \theta$, $\cos \theta$, etc.) of any random angle(for example $67°$ or $32°$ or $82°$) and most of the internet's results were through taylor series approximation(which is quite time consuming and requires a lot of calculations).

I want to know is there any other way than taylor series approximation, that can provide an approximation without very large calculations, and without any help sheets(like log tables)?

Comment: See [How to intuitively understand how the trig ratios are calculated](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/17863/745). Note that my comment (not an answer) to this other question gives a specific example of a well known 1800s trigonometry text where the calculation methods are discussed. Many similar such books (freely available on the internet) can be found by a [google books search for *trigonometry+tables*, restricted to the 19th century](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1899&tbm=bks&q=trigonometry+tables).

Comment: What are "trigonometric ratios", and what are angles "in multiple of $15$"?

Comment: People in the 1800s didn't have access to a calculator, and your comment about "help sheets" suggests that there is a lot of missing context in your question.

Comment: In some exam settings it may help if you can remember or quickly reconstruct trig functions of 30, 45, and 60 degrees, and also remember that the smallest angle of a 3-4-5 right triangle is approximately 37 degrees. Is that what you're asking about? That's very different from "any random angle".